# Pl sql- reading mathematical formula and replacing with number

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following tables:

```
TABLE  1                                                         TABLE 2

Col 1        Col2                                              A      $100
 Rpt1     (A + B(1-D))/C                                       B      $200
 Rpt2         -A                                               C      $300
 Rpt3         C+D                                              D      $400
```

I want to write a PL-SQL code that reads both the tables and give me the below dynamically.

```
Rpt 1  =  (100 +200(1-400))/300
Rpt 2  =  - 100
Rpt 3  =  300+400
```

Table 1 can have any type of formula.  I need to read that formula and replace it with the amount present in table 2.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for PL/SQL, here's a nested loop solution:

```
create table table1 (col1, col2) as
select 'Rpt1', '(A + B(1-D))/C' from dual union all
select 'Rpt2', '-A' from dual union all
select 'Rpt3', 'C+D' from dual;

create table table2 (col1, col2) as
select 'A', 100 from dual union all
select 'B', 200 from dual union all
select 'C', 300 from dual union all
select 'D', 400 from dual;

set serveroutput on

declare
  result varchar2(100);
begin
  for r1 in (select col1, col2 from table1)
  loop
    result := r1.col2;
    for r2 in (select col1, col2 from table2 where result like '%' || col1 || '%')
    loop
      result := replace(result, r2.col1, r2.col2);
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(r1.col1 || '  =  ' || result);
  end loop;
end;
/

Rpt1  =  (100 + 200(1-400))/300
Rpt2  =  -100
Rpt3  =  300+400


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I've assumed that the dollar signs aren't actually present in `table2`; if they are then you'll need to trim them off if you don't want then in the output.

Comment: . . If the OP had asked for a SQL solution, would you also have an answer? ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm still thinking about that *8-) At the moment I have a messy recursive CTE approach that generates too many intermediate rows. Or a 12cR2 CTE with a function within it, which I'm not too keen on either. But I'd have been reluctant to post a PL/SQL solution if the OP hadn't asked for one, even as a stop-gap...

Comment: . . I thought you might have had a solution, but just a bit too long to fit into the margins.